# Android phone Lg Realm(ls620) no driver found and can't find one online

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb, lg

I can't get android studio to see my brand new lg phone that I bought specifically for debugging. I'm really sad now as the phone is really cool but I can't debug with it. I enabled developer mode by tapping the build number list item 7 times, and put usb debugging mode on. I tried both Media Sync(MTP) and Send Images(PTP) modes with no luck. I'm really stuck without this thing working.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should try desactivating *both* mtp and PTP

Comment: you're right you have to do both the answer I put up and deactivating both of those modes.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using googles universal usb driver here's how.

I followed all the instructions at this site:
http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php
in case that site ever goes down here are the steps.

step 1:
install the google usb driver through your android sdk manager it's at the very bottom.

step 2: go to the device manager and fine your phone it should have the yellow caution icon

step 3:  right click the phone in the device manager and click browse my computer for driver software

step 4: when that screen comes up don't put anything in the textbox instead click on "let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" button

step 5: hit "show all devices"

step 6: click the "have disk" button that shows up

step 7: put the path to your sdk google drivers in that textbox example: C:\Program Files\ADT\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

step 8: when the item "android adb interface" shows up click it,click next, then click install

Answer (score 0):

Installing the google generic drivers from the SDK then using those drivers for your phone works!